# Yii Configuration References Location

Tags: php, yii

I understand how the `~/protected/config/main.php` work like

```
'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test_blog',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'gusdecool',
        'password' => 'gusdecool',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'tablePrefix'=> 'tbl_'
    )
```

the DB reference is locate [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbConnection), i understand the array key represent public properties of that class.

Where is the reference location on Yii Website for Configuration of `~/protected/config/main.php`?
I need to know this, for understand all of the configuration we can make, also if i didn't define that configuration. What is the config it will take.

Please inform if my question is unclear :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the docs for the CWebApplication class:  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebApplication the various components in the config/main.php file map to the public properties of this class.  Similarly, `config/console.php` maps to CConsoleApplication.

Comment: in the first, i think that is right. but after read that page, It give me another question. Why `db` configuration putted under `components` array? Since in `CWebApplication` there is public properties for `db`, isn't that mean we can put `db` config on level 1 array instead on level 2 array (under `components`)?

Comment: All the application components (most anything extending CApplicationComponent) are part of the `components` array. If you look at the `getDB` code that the `db` attribute maps to, it's just doing `getComponent('db')`.  There's no `setDB` method, so attempting to set `db` configuration in the level 1 array will fail.